# Why is getMethod() throwing this exception?

Tags: java, reflection

I am dynamically loading an object and executing one of it's methods in java.

```
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
c = ucl.loadClass(classname);
theParser = c.newInstance();
Object temp = theParser;
Class a = c;
//  Method m = c.getMethod("constructorCore",
//          uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text.class);
Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
String fmt = "%24s: %s%n";
for (Method m : allMethods) {

    System.out.format("%s%n", m.toGenericString());

    System.out.format(fmt, "ReturnType", m.getReturnType());
    System.out.format(fmt, "GenericReturnType",
            m.getGenericReturnType());

    Class<?>[] pType = m.getParameterTypes();
    Type[] gpType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
    for (int i = 0; i < pType.length; i++) {
        System.out.format(fmt, "ParameterType", pType[i]);
        System.out.format(fmt, "GenericParameterType", gpType[i]);
    }

    Class<?>[] xType = m.getExceptionTypes();
    Type[] gxType = m.getGenericExceptionTypes();
    for (int i = 0; i < xType.length; i++) {
        System.out.format(fmt, "ExceptionType", xType[i]);
        System.out.format(fmt, "GenericExceptionType", gxType[i]);
    }
}
```

I got the for loop from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodType.html and it tells me what the types are of the methods in the class.

Two of the methods used are (output by this code) are:

```
public void imp.GLLParser.constructorCore(int)
              ReturnType: void
       GenericReturnType: void
           ParameterType: int
    GenericParameterType: int
public void imp.GLLParser.constructorCore(uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text)
              ReturnType: void
       GenericReturnType: void
           ParameterType: class uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text
    GenericParameterType: class uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text
```

But when I run the line (currently commented)

```
Method m = c.getMethod("constructorCore",
                uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text.class);
```

I get the exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: imp.GLLParser.constructorCore(uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1773)
    at dynamicParser.GLLParser.<init>(GLLParser.java:46)
```

Which is driving me nuts.

If I use

```
 Method m = c.getMethod("constructorCore",
                    int.class);
```

I can call the `int` version NO problem.

What's happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try `c.getDeclaredMethod` instead of `c.getMethod`

Comment: When you can do this call, the `uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text` class must already be loaded. Are you sure that this class does not exist *twice* in your classpath? You might quickly check this by some debug output, roughly like `System.out.println(pType[i].equals(uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text.class)` in the parameter type loop. This should print `true` at least once - namely, for the method you are trying to load.

Comment: Can you try `System.out.format(fmt, "ParameterType", pType[i]+" is Text: " + pType[i].equals(uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text.class));`  With class loaders you can have multiple classes with the same name but they are not equal as they were loaded with different loaders.

Comment: What is the actual implementation of the method you are trying to call ? (eg: `void constructorCore( uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text text)` ?

Comment: Whoop! Marco13 and Peter's comments correctly diagnosed the problem and got me to a solution.  Thanks both - if either of you want to make your comment into an answer that would be lovely...  I just needed to change uk.ac.rhul.csle.text.Text into a class loaded by the same classloader.